# Update some database fields when post is saved

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class that will count the Lines of Code, Source Lines of Code, and the Code disk space used.  I would like to save these values into the database so that these values can be calculated only when a new post is saved or updated instead of running the code on every page view

So my question is, what is the best way to make sure these are added/updated everytime a new post is made and everytime that post is updated/edited.

Also where should I store these, in a custom meta field?  If so, how can I make sure that the meta box does not show up on the page, it should all be done behind the scenes

Comment: Def: Meta Data.

Comment: **TIP:** If you use a `meta_key` starting with an underscore it will be hidden from view(that's how core does it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for storing them is [Wordpress' Options Mechanism](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#WordPress_Options_Mechanism).

ANd best way to trigger it when a post saved is using Wordpress [save_post action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

Example :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'count' ); //Execute count() when a post saved/updated
function count()
{
    your codes here ...

    //save them to DB
    update_option("lines-of-code", $lines);
    update_option("disk-space", $diskspace);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need this saved for every post though so the options thing wouldn't work as it is for saving 1 key/value for the site and not 1 for each post.  You `save_post` action will be useful though