# Update field in database for users

Tags: posts, database, options

I have made a frontend form for the admins where they can check a checkbox for each user and submit the form data by post.

For all the users that are checked, a value should be changed in a field in the database. The slug for this field could be `payment_status`.

What is a method to update or change the value of a field in the database for **a specific user**?

I have looked at a question like this: [Update some database fields when post is saved](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/update-some-database-fields-when-post-is-saved)

And have been trying with the [options methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#WordPress_Options_Mechanism) in wordpress.

But I have trouble finding the way to change the value for the specific user. When this is possible for me, it might not be difficult to convert this into repeating the update process for every checked user in the post data.

Comment: Have you seen the [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) WordPress function?

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesClarkson. Why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: It was too short. Some moderator probably would have moved it to a comment. It has happened before. :) Did it help?

Comment: @CharlesClarkson Yep, that was what I had missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) WordPress function?